# How to make my while loop work in Python?

Tags: python, loops, while-loop

This is my code:

```
import random
Random = random.randint(1, 10)
print("Number:" + str(Random))
Number = int(input("Guess the number I am thinking of from 1-10"))
while int(Random) != Number:
  if(Random > Number):
    Number = input("Too low. Guess again!")
  elif(Number > Random):
    Number = input("Too high. Guess again!")
print("You guessed it!")
```

When the correct number is guessed, this happens, which is what is supposed to happen.

```
Number:8
Guess the number I am thinking of from 1-10 8
You guessed it!
```

But, when the number isn't guessed correctly, it loops though the elif statement only.

```
Number:10
Guess the number I am thinking of from 1-10 6
Too low. Guess again! 7
Too high. Guess again! 6
Too high. Guess again! 5
Too high. Guess again! 4
Too high. Guess again! 3
Too high. Guess again! 2
Too high. Guess again! 1
Too high. Guess again! 10
Too high. Guess again! 9
Too high. Guess again! 8
```

Comment: You need more `int()`s around your `input()`s

Comment: @StephenRauch I thought you meant `int(int(int(int(input()))))` for a moment :P

Comment: I can't reproduce the issue with the code you posted. After guessing a second time I got `TypeError: '>' not supported between instances of 'int' and 'str'`. You need to provide a [mre]. BTW welcome to Stack Overflow! Check out the [tour] and [ask].

Comment: @OP Don't capitalize your variables, btw.

Comment: @wjandrea depends on whether you're using Python 2 or 3.

Comment: @CS Oh, you're right. I assume everyone is using Python 3 these days since 2 is EOL.

Comment: That said though, I still can't reproduce the issue. When I set `Random = 10` and input 6, 7, and 6, I consistently get "Too low" and inputting 10 works properly.

Comment: Naming a variable `random` is probably a bad idea.

Comment: @Grismar Please don't change variable names in edits, even if it's only a case difference. Pretty much the only part of Python code you should edit is whitespace, and only if it's non-functional. See [When should I make edits to code?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/260245/4518341)

Comment: @wjandrea fair enough - apologies, better as remarks in the answer.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried casting int onto the input within both input lines in the while loop? It seems to work for me when it's like:

```
if(Random > Number):
    Number = int(input("Too low. Guess again!"))
elif(Number > Random):
    Number = int(input("Too high. Guess again!"))
```

Answer (score 0):

```
import random
number=random.randint(1,10)
guess=int(input("Guess the number I am thinking of from 1-10")
while guess !=number:
    if guess < number:
       print("Your answer was too low...")
    else:
       print("Your number was too high...")
    guess= int(input("Please try again...")
print("Congratulations! Correct answer!")
```

you can use this as your reference. thank you...

Comment: It will be much more helpful if you could explain what are the issues in the question code and how you address them in your answer.

Answer (score 0):

This is an improved version of your code:

```
import random

answer = random.randint(1, 10)
print("Number:" + str(answer))
guess = int(input("Guess the number I am thinking of from 1-10"))
while answer != guess:
    if guess < answer:
        guess = int(input("Too low. Guess again!"))
    elif guess > answer:
        guess = int(input("Too high. Guess again!"))
print("You guessed it!")
```

Some remarks on the changes:

- The main thing is the `int()` around the `input()`. `input()` gets you a value as a string, but you want to compare the values of the numbers, not the strings. For example `'12' < '2'` but `12 > 2`.
- Your variables' names had capital letters in them, that's a bad idea in Python, since that signals to editors and other programmers that they're classes instead of variables.
- Your variable `Random` had the same name as the module you're using, making it easy to get confused, `answer` seemed like a better choice.
- Your code was indented with 2 spaces, but most editors default to 4 and that's also inline with standard Python style guidelines.
- Instead of flipping the order of variables, it's often best to make your code read as close as possible to what it means; for example, `if guess < answer` is exactly what you're saying: "too low".